# jQuery synchronous AJAX call in IE and Chrome hides "thinking" animated icon

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I am having a problem with Internet Explorer showing and hiding the "thinking" icon on synchronous calls. I understand the difference between async and sync, but it should be that synchronous calls allow the image to be displayed, the AJAX to be performed, then image to be hidden. In Firefox the image shows, AJAX is performed, and image disappears... but this does not happen in IE and Chrome.

```
function get(url, cache){

  var resp;

    $('#pmt_ajaximg').show();

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      context: document.body,
      cache: cache,
      success: function(response){
        if(response && response.hello){
            console.log(response.hello);
        }
            $('#pmt_ajaximg').hide();
      }
    });
}
```

I've tried moving the `$('#pmt_ajaximg').hide()` to it's own `complete()` function in the `$.ajax object` but that did not work either. Interestingly, if I comment out the `$('#pmt_ajaximg').hide()` completely, I do in fact see the image show up and stay there, so I know it's working initially.

Additionally, I also added a `console.log('test')` to the `success()` function and it shows up AFTER the result is returned from the AJAX, but the `$('#pmt_ajaximg').hide()` appears to run right away, thus hiding the `$('#pmt_ajaximg').show()`'s effects before it has a chance to show.

Also, before anyone says it may be so quick the image doesn't have time to display, note that this is a simplified version of the function and the real one definitely does take some time, and as I said, shows up in FF.

Very strange. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spinner  in Chrome, IE9 does not become visible during synchronous  ajax get request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452817/spinner-in-chrome-ie9-does-not-become-visible-during-synchronous-ajax-get-req)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that during the synchronous AJAX request, the browser engine doesn't leave the JavaScript thread and doesn't update the screen.

It's explained better on [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452817/spinner-in-chrome-ie9-does-not-become-visible-during-synchronous-ajax-get-req).

Answer (score 0):

In my work, I had solved this kind of issue by doing something similar and it worked fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```
$('#pmt_ajaximg').show();

setTimeout(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      context: document.body,
      cache: cache,
      success: function(response){
        if(response && response.hello){
            console.log(response.hello);
        }
            $('#pmt_ajaximg').hide();
      }
    });
}, 0);
```